# Random crash on android

Tags: android, crash, native

I have random crashes on an android app.
This is a hybrid application, where most of the business logic resides in a remote server, seems like something in that web view causes the crash

when debugged it runs normally, only when not debugged I get this trace

```
12-17 09:53:27.051: I/Web Console(20949): page create called:76    
12-17 09:53:27.131: A/libc(20949): @@@ ABORTING: heap corruption detected by tmalloc_large    
12-17 09:53:27.131: A/libc(20949): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 21040 (WebViewCoreThre)    


#00 pc 0001e824 /system/lib/libc.so    
#01 pc 0001c76c /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)    
#02 pc 000122ed /system/lib/libc.so    
#03 pc 0000ea11 /system/lib/libc.so    
#04 pc 0000f8df /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+606)    
#05 pc 0000daab /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+10)    
#06 pc 0000091b /system/lib/libstdc++.so (operator new(unsigned int)+2)    
#07 pc 002a9421 /system/lib/libwebcore.so    
#08 pc 002a94e9 /system/lib/libwebcore.so    
#09 pc 002a9521 /system/lib/libwebcore.so    
#10 pc 0001e44c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)    
#11 pc 0004e91b /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)    
#12 pc 00027860 /system/lib/libdvm.so    
#13 pc 0002be00 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)    
#14 pc 00060a6d /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+292)    
#15 pc 00060a97 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)    
#16 pc 0005582b /system/lib/libdvm.so    
#17 pc 0000cb58 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)    
#18 pc 0000ccd4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
```

with this message:

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/m0xx/m0:4.3/JSS15J/I9300XXUGMK7:user/release-keys'    
Revision: '12'    
pid: 4541, tid: 4587, name: WebViewCoreThre >>> ------- ---- <<<    
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad    
Abort message: '@@@ ABORTING: heap corruption detected by tmalloc_large'    
r0 00000027 r1 00000000 r2 00000008 r3 deadbaad    
r4 00000000 r5 62a97754 r6 5b3254c0 r7 5b3254c0    
r8 4001c000 r9 00000001 sl 00004dff fp 62a97c84    
ip 00000001 sp 62a97750 lr 401722ff pc 4016f824 cpsr 60000030    
d0 3f00000000000000 d1 3f847ae147ae147b    
d2 419ffffffc000000 d3 42c7cccd00000000    
d4 4059000000000000 d5 42c8000044204000    
d6 43b4000043b40000 d7 4420400000000281    
d8 bff0000000000000 d9 bff0000000000000    
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000    
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000    
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000    
d16 0000000000000000 d17 0000000000000000    
d18 bf847ae147ae147b d19 ffffffffffffffff    
d20 00e700e700e700e7 d21 00e700e700e700e7    
d22 fff7fff7fff7fff7 d23 fff7fff7fff7fff7    
d24 4058f9999999999a d25 0040004000400040    
d26 00e700e700e700e7 d27 4059000000000000    
d28 00c900c900c900c9 d29 00c900c900c900c9    
d30 0080008000800080 d31 0080008000800080    
scr 60000013    


code around pc:    
4016f804 461ce00b 2b006823 e026d1fb b12468e4     
4016f814 21014a18 6011447a 4b1247a0 24002027     
4016f824 f7fc7018 2106edc2 e828f7fe 5180f04f     
4016f834 a9029104 94022006 9403460a ebc4f7fd     
4016f844 46224629 f7fd2002 f7fcebd0 2106edae     
4016f854 e814f7fe f7fc2001 6960ea5a d1dc2800     
4016f864 bf00e7d4 deadbaad 000297f4 ffffff9c     
4016f874 0002ca84 0002ca68 2400b510 aa04b088     
4016f884 46699002 94014620 94039400 eb12f7fd     
4016f894 db0642a0 b1139b07 1c419806 98069106     
4016f8a4 4620e000 bd10b008 4b1eb40e b082b5f0     
4016f8b4 447b491d f107af00 585e021c f8522101     
4016f8c4 68354b04 f852607d 31015b04 d1fa2d00     
4016f8d4 320e008a 0507f022 0220f107 0d05ebad     
4016f8e4 f107603a 46690224 9400466d 4c04f852     
4016f8f4 f8453204 2c004f04 f8dfd1f8 f853c030     

code around lr:    
401722dc 4a0e4b0d e92d447b 260041f0 4680589c     
401722ec 686768a5 f9b5e007 2b00300c 4628dd02     
401722fc 430647c0 3f013554 6824d5f5 d1ef2c00     
4017230c e8bd4630 bf0081f0 00026cf4 ffffffc4     
4017231c 43f0e92d fb01461e 4b16f502 4916460f     
4017232c 447bb087 aa014614 20019001 95029203     
4017233c 90049505 681a585b b1124698 f0094630     
4017234c 4630fd4a f7ffa903 4681fe9c 0000f8d8     
4017235c 4630b110 fd4cf009 0f00f1b9 9c05d005     
4017236c 1b284639 ecbcf017 46204604 e8bdb007     
4017237c bf0083f0 00026ca6 ffffff60 46036842     
4017238c 60411e51 da012900 bbbcf000 f8126802     
4017239c 601a0b01 00004770 4a104b0f b570447b     
401723ac 589b4604 461e6819 f009b109 6860fd14     
401723bc 60651e45 da042d00 f0004620 4605fba3     
401723cc 6822e003 5b01f812 68336022 4620b113
```

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: why does it crash, I managed to isolate the problem - the crash is due to redirect on a webview, still ... I don't understand why it should crash